# Optimizely Dialog (Pagepicker, Category picker and Media picker)

Tags: dojo, optimizely, dijit.dialog

I have a custom made Wastebasket. Clicking restore on an item with Wastebasket as direct parent will just restore the item directly back to where it belonged before, but when i want to restore a child of an item, i would need to pick where to put it. I would prefer doing this with a Dojo/dijit dialog like the one Optimizely use in the original Wastebasket. There the content of the dialog changes based on IContent type.

Is there any way of doing this with pure html/js and with a callback for chosen content?

Thank u for ur answers!